# Call a class whose name is in a string

Tags: java

I'm trying to call a class whose part of the name is included in a string obtained by reading console input.

```
static void menu() {

        System.out.println("Choose a menu:");
        System.out.print("\n");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String nome = null;
        try {
            nome = reader.readLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
        System.out.println("Opening: " + nome);
        System.out.print("\n");

        String funzione = nome + ".funzione();";

        try {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(funzione);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(funzione);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Basically, if I write "print", I'd like to execute `print.function();` which is called later in the program. The code works but it also outputs an error `java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "print.function();": error=2, No such file or directory`, yet `print.function();` gets executed anyway.

To be clear, I am intentionally following this method rather than a switch case.

I think I'm executing the process in a wrong way, could anyone highlight me where? Many thanks.

Comment: is `print.function()` a java function? If so, you need to use reflection.

Comment: `I'm trying to call a class whose part of the name is included in a string obtained by reading console input.` you will need reflection for this. But it sounds like XY question. Why do you need to do it?

Comment: You need to use `Reflection` not `Runtime`. If print is the class and function is the function it would be. `Class.forName("printer").getDeclaredMethod("function", null).invoke(getMyPrinterObject(), null)`

Comment: Just providing class name is not enough for reflection.You also need to provide the fully qualified class name. how will know if your class in a particular package when you get a part of it from user input.

Comment: Didn't know about Reflection. Even with `Class.forName(name).getDeclaredMethod(function, null);` I still get the same error, but the function call still works and gets executed after the error